# Autorelease in custom init methods

Tags: objective-c

I'm a little confused about the principles of autoreleasing objects from custom init methods. For example:

```
- (id)initWithId: (unsigned long)personID {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.ID = personID;
    }

    return self;
}
```

According to the objc coding conventions I must autorelease self on return. But that kind of code keeps crushing. Am I'm missing something? Should I autorelease only those objects I create manually in those methods, but not "self", like this?

```
- (id)makeWithId: (unsigned long)personID {
    Person *obj = [[Person init] alloc];

    if (obj) {
        obj.ID = personID;
    }

    return [obj autorelease];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you holding on to the object that is being returned in the calling code?

Comment: It does not matter =) It's all about the principle of autorelease. What I mean: If I'm calling `SomeClass sc = [SomeClass alloc] init];` I will definitely release sc after I use it. But if I'm calling `SomeClass sc = [[SomeClass alloc] initWithSomeParam:123]` I dont need to release it, I'm not responsible for it (initWithSomeParam is).

Comment: @Stormherz, you're wrong there. If you've called `alloc`, you're responsible for releasing it. If you had called `[SomeClass someClassWithSomeParam:5]`, you're not responsible for it, it's autoreleased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cocoa, there is this convention:

- Methods that start with `alloc` or `new` return an object with retain count +1
- all other methods that create an object return an autoreleased object.

Note that with the `init` method you posted above, an object isn't created. The previous `alloc` call creates the object. This just sets it up and makes it ready for use.

As for your `makeWithId` method, you've confused two concepts. A factory method like this should be a class method (i.e. declared with a `+`, not a `-`). Then you will use it like

```
Person *p = [Person makeWithId:3];
```

As it stands, you're returning a different object than the receiver of the method call. That means that when you do

```
Person *p = [[Person alloc] makeWithId:3];
```

The `Person` object created with `alloc` has been leaked, and `p` is autoreleased.

So, to summarise, return autoreleased objects from class 'factory' methods, and don't do any memory management in `init` methods.

Comment: arghhh, I'm not allocating anything here, my empty head, I sure overworked this time =) Thanks a lot, it's all make sense now.

Answer (score 2):

You do not allocating anything, so you don't have to release something.

You can autorelease your object when you create it.

```
YourClass *yourOblect = [YourClass alloc] initWithId:27] autorelease];
[yourObject doSomething];
.....
```